# Ansible unarchive: "Failed to find handler"

Tags: ansible

When I unarchive a file with Ansible, the following error occurred:

> Failed to find handler to unarchive. Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed.

Is there a solution without installing the required modules (gtar / unzip).

Answer (score 7):

No. Ansible is no magic, it is an automation tool which relies on commonly available tools to perform its tasks.

Per [unarchive](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html) documentation:

> requires gtar/unzip command on target host

If you look at the source, it [looks for](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/files/unarchive.py#L589) `gtar` (preferred) then `tar` and [`unzip`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/files/unarchive.py#L187).

---

You can always use `command` / `shell` modules to run any command you like, but still you'd need programs to extract from the archives on the target machine.

Comment: And that allowed you to unarchive without the executables being present?

Answer (score 1):

The same message might be output even if the source file type is not a compressed file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer is a great guide on how to answer questions in Stack Overflow.  Fuller explanations are a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the archive file to be extracted is indeed an archive. In my case it was "HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines (785)".

Example:
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.8.2/apache-zookeeper-3.8.2.tar.gz